# How to compile C code using R CMD SHLIB to use OpenMP?

Tags: c, r, openmp

I am trying to implement openMP in some C code that I am calling from R.  Right now I am using a test program to see how many threads I have available, but I can't seem to get more than one thread.  How can I get more than one thread when this program runs?

Here are the contents of test_omp.c:

```
#ifdef _OPENMP
  #include <omp.h>
#endif
#include <stdio.h>
#include <R.h>

void test_omp(){
  int num_threads=-1;
  #ifdef _OPENMP
    printf("We have Open MP!\n");
    omp_set_num_threads(2);
    num_threads = omp_get_num_threads();
  #else
    printf(":(\n");
  #endif
  printf("Number of OpenMP threads: %d\n",num_threads);
}
```

I then compile this using the shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2
export PKG_CFLAGS="-fopenmp"
export PKG_LIBS="-lgomp"
R CMD SHLIB test_omp.c
```

I then run the following code in R

```
dyn.load("test_omp.so")
.C("test_omp")
```

and I get the following output:

```
We have Open MP!
Number of OpenMP threads: 1
```

I am expecting to get 2 threads, but I am only getting one.  How can I get more than one thread?

Comment: what do you mean `how many threads I have available`? At the time this program runs - it has 1 thread, if you create more - you will have more

Comment: @llya Bursov -- I know I have one thread at runtime -- that's the problem.  In order to run openMP effectively, I need to have more than one.  How would I create more?

Comment: how you even tried to read any manual? try this example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdeb73hc.aspx first

Comment: @llya Bursov - I understand now.  Since I was calling `omp_get_num_threads()` outside of a `#pragma omp parallel` code segment, I was only getting one thread.  If, however, I call `omp_get_num_threads()` within an `#pragma omp parallel'` segment, my R code displays 2, the number I was originally expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @llya Bursov's comments, I figured out the solution.  The reason why only one thread was found was because I was calling `omp_get_num_threads()` outside of a `#pragma omp parallel` block.  If I modify the code and place  `omp_get_num_threads()` inside of a `#pragma omp parallel` block, I get the two threads that I was expecting:

```
#ifdef _OPENMP
  #include <omp.h>
#endif
#include <stdio.h>
#include <R.h>

void test_omp(){
  int num_threads=-1;
  #ifdef _OPENMP
    printf("We have Open MP!\n");
    omp_set_num_threads(2);
    #pragma omp parallel
      #pragma omp master
        {
          // num_threads = omp_get_num_threads();
          printf("Number of OpenMP threads: %d\n",omp_get_num_threads());
        }
  #else
    printf(":(\n");
  #endif
  printf("Number of OpenMP threads: %d\n",num_threads);
}
```

I get the following output from R (after compiling as above):

```
We have Open MP!
Number of OpenMP threads: 2
Number of OpenMP threads: -1
```